# How to override new-tab page in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to write a sample extension to override newtab page with some html content provided from javascript. How to do this ? 
Javascript to provide html content here :

```
function getFavouriteWebsite() {

    var historyService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-history-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsINavHistoryService);
    var query = historyService.getNewQuery();
    var options = historyService.getNewQueryOptions();
    options.queryType = 0;
    options.sortingMode = options.SORT_BY_VISITCOUNT_DESCENDING;
    options.maxResults = 6;
    var result = historyService.executeQuery(query, options);
    result.root.containerOpen = true;
    var contentHtml ='';
    for (var i = 0; i < result.root.childCount; i++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.root.childCount; i++) {
            contentHtml += "<p><a href=\"" + result.root.getChild(i).uri + "\">" +               (result.root.getChild(i).title == "" ? result.root.getChild(i).uri : result.root.getChild(i).title) + "</a></p>";
        }
    }
    return contentHtml;
}
```

Comment: What's the issue? Is it with querying the history service, or actually getting HTML on the new tab page?

Answer (score 0):

To override the newtab page, set the `browser.newtab.url` preference to some HTML/XUL document. Include whatever scripts in that document to populate the content.

But please do not string-concatenate html fragments together as you'd likely end up with insecure code, but use DOM APIs such as `document.createElement()`, `Node.textContent`, `Node.setAttribute` etc instead.